# How can I launch an exe within a conda env

Tags: anaconda, visual-studio-code, conda, miniconda

I'm using vscode in Windows 10 as my code editor, and want to make an easy way to launch it with the correct conda env to allow debugging.

Currently I am having to open a command prompt, then activate the conda env, then paste the shortcut to vscode into the prompt to execute. Like so:

```
cmd
activate env-name
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

I have tried creating a batch file to wrap these calls, but unfortunately once I call "source activate" to start the conda env, the batch commands after this are not executed as it is considered another instance.

Any tips? Other than writing a vscode extension to handle this (which I'm seriously tempted to do, but it's such a simple problem...)

Comment: I wonder how is "source activate" working for you, since you're using Windows. On windows you use only "activate"

Comment: @EdisonGustavoMuenz You are correct, edited above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activating Anaconda Environment in VsCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351596/activating-anaconda-environment-in-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to run `source activate env-name` as a task in visual studio.
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

#### tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "cmd",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "development",
            "args": ["source", "activate", "env-name"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work - it simply launches a cmd window as a sub-process of vscode.exe, so no environment changes are inherited by the vscode process.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I found is to set the `python.venvPath` parameter in [vscode settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) to your anaconda envs folder.

```
"python.venvPath": "/Users/[...]/Anaconda3/envs"
```

Then if you bring up the command palette (`ctl + shift + P` on windows/linux, `cmd + shift + P` on mac) and type `Python: Select Workspace Interpreter` all your envs will show up and you can select which env to use.

The [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python) will also need to be installed for the Select Workspace Interpreter option.

Note: The Select Workspace Interpreter takes around 10 seconds to come up on my computer using the current version of VSCode. My answer was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007744/2826818).

Answer (score 0):

Using Conda 4.7.5, I was able to change the Target under the VsCode taskbar shortcut Properties from:

`"C:\Users\Paul.siersma\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"`

To:

`C:\Users\Paul.siersma\Anaconda3\_conda.exe run -p C:\Users\Paul.siersma\Anaconda3 "C:\Users\Paul.siersma\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"`

This uses the `run` command (marked experimental) and starts VSCode using the base Conda environment. You could specify another environment by changing the `-p` flag to the environment location eg `-p [..]\Anaconda3\envs\myenv`