# Unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I know this question is asked a lot, I searched for the last three hours for an answer, but couldn't solve my problem.

As soon as I try to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

my Visual Studio Code IDE tells me that: *Unable to import 'matplotlib.pyplot'*

My current version of Python is:

Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin

as you can see, I used the Anaconda package, hence matplotlib should be included. I am Using Mac OS 10.15.2

If I enter

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

it does import that, however, as soon as I try a basic example, like

```
x = [1,2,3] 
y = [2,4,1] 
plt.plot(x, y)
```

I obtain:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10c23d950>]
```

And a blank token in my Dashboard pops up, which I can only force to quit.

In the course of trying to solve this problem, I tried anything I saw that was related to this topic, although I did not understand everything of it. I hope I did not make a real damage. 
My last step was completely deinstalling anaconda and reinstalling.

Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: It's a linting error, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module can be imported, but your IDE says `module not found`, means your linter (vscode uses pylinter) is not configured correctly.

[Start PyLint from correct anaconda environment in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092182/start-pylint-from-correct-anaconda-environment-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I did the steps as described, the only environment I could choose was ```base```. Hence I did ```source activate base``` and ```conda install pylint``` successfully. However, my problem is not solved by that. I tried as well the second answer in that thread and added ```--load-plugins``` as well as ```pylint_django``` to my preferences, this resulted in the fact that the line was not red underlined, but as soon as I start debugging and run the program, the error occurs again.

Comment: Why `pylint_django`? It's for django, not matplotlib

Comment: I doubt it's the linter.  It's probably that the version of Python itself is mismatched between the environment where you installed Anaconda, and VS Code.  I submitted an answer below that might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> First you need to install package matplotlib using conda console in your project

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

> You also can install package using PIP

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

And Finally import your package in your source code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Or another Way you can import

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Comment: I get the message: ```All requested packages already installed.``` The error occurs further.

Answer (score 0):

Having come here with this error myself, especially if you're using VS Code you need to make sure that the version of Python you're running in VS Code is the same one that's running on your OS.  Otherwise, you can `conda install` or `pip3 install` all you want into the OS, but VS Code and Jupyter Notebooks won't know anything about those modules.  There are a few ways to figure this out, but mostly it's making sure that the Python version you see when typing `python --version` in the terminal matches the interpreter shown in the top-right corner of your VS Code window.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and this worked for me in a jupyter notebook in vs code. I ran this as its own cell before running the cell with all my imports. I had to do this for another package in the past. Not sure why the normal method of pip install in the vs code terminal didn't work but at least this worked:

`import sys`

`!{sys.executable} -m pip install matplotlib`

Comment: You should be able to use the more user-friendly version of the magic install commands in the notebook now. `%pip install` or `%conda install`.  No need for an import and more concise. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic install commands that insure in Jupyter the installations occur in the environment underlying the active notebook in which you run them. Equivalent for your case is `%pip install matplotlib`.