# Pylint: how to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib

I know I have matplotlib installed but I get an error when trying to run it. I tried to follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45092182/12136547). but when I run it again I get the following:

```
python -u "/Users/MacBook/python/code/stats.py"
/Users/MacBook/.fzf.zsh:source:13: no such file or directory: /Users/xxxxx 1/.fzf/shell/key-bindings.zsh
/Users/MacBook/.zshrc:export:2: not valid in this context: Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/bin:/usr/vac/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin:.:/Users/xxxxx
MacBook@MacBook-Air python % python -u "/Users/MacBook/python/code/stats.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MacBook/python/code/stats.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

This happens in VS code: I am running python 3.9.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, so here a few things I tried:

- Switch interpreter to python with conda in the name
- reload VS code
- if that still doesn't work, try to activate via `source activate Macbook`