# vscode debugging with conda: how to access root pkgs?

Tags: python, anaconda, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[Conda and Visual Studio Code debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700354/conda-and-visual-studio-code-debugging)

I saw the above answer and was able to choose the correct Conda env from `Python: Select Interpreter` on the the `Cmd-Shift-P` command palette. However, I installed `tensorflow` in the root environment and in the current config it is not available from the vscode debugger.

I need to add this line at the top of my script to makes things work in debug:

```
sys.path.append('/[...]/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
import tensorflow as tf
```

how do I configure this properly within `vscode`?

NOTE: if I install `tensorflow` in my active conda env, then all works fine. but I should have to do that, right?

Comment: Yes, you have to install it in your active conda env. That's how conda works.

Comment: I thought whatever was installed in the conda base/root env was global.

Comment: Surely that's not true.