# Import errors when debugging Python unit tests in VSCode

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a Python unit test inside Visual Studio Code, but am getting an error while importing dependencies at the top of the file:

```
import unittest
from scipy.io import loadmat  # exception thrown here
```

I get a lengthy exception message:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)`
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
...
```

This happens only when debugging.  Any ideas why?  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using any virtualenvs/multiple Python versions, is your terminal/vscode running in the right one?

Comment: Yep, I'm using an anaconda virtual environment and the terminal is set to it.  Do I need to configure this in some other places as well for debugging sessions?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700354/conda-and-visual-studio-code-debugging

Comment: Thanks @mikulatomas, of all the ideas suggested on that SO, the solution that worked was to open a cmd window, do conda activate, navigate to my project folder and start code . from that folder.  I'm uneasy about accepting this hack as a solution.  I feel there should be a more permanent way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the way around is to open Anaconda Powershell and type:

```
cd <my project folder>
conda activate <myenv>
code .
```

This starts VSCode with the correct configuration.  It's an ugly hack, but allows me to run and debug my unit tests.