# Modules installed in Conda environment not being found by VS code

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, visual-studio-code

I have Python 3.6 installed using Anaconda as the sole Python instance on my computer.
Following the [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) on TensorFlow, I created a conda environment called *tensorflow* running Python 3.5, activated it and ran 
***pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow*** to install tensorflow.
While inside the environment I am able to validate the installation by running *import tensorflow*, which works fine.
To run my scripts in this environment in VS Code, I followed the instructions on [configuring Python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) and selected the interpreter such that it corresponds 
to the conda environment I created. This adjusts the python path variable in VS Code's user settings accordingly.

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 2,
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Abyss",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\osharaki\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\python.exe"
}
```

However, when I try to run a script inside VS Code that imports tensorflow I still receive the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

The resource that came closest to answering my issue was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351596/activating-anaconda-environment-in-vscode).

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you run `C:\Users\osharaki\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe -c "import tensorflow"`?

Comment: Runs, but gives the numpy warning "RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
  return f(*args, **kwds)"

Comment: Have you tried "conda install tensorflow" or "conda upgrade tensorflow"?

Comment: No, I haven't. It might be worth mentioning that in Pycharm I am able to edit the configuration and select the interpreter to be the 'tensorflow' environment I created, which works fine.

Comment: And how are you running the code? From the terminal or using "Run Python File in Terminal"?

Comment: I'm using Task Runner to run the code in VS Code.

Comment: _I created a conda environment called tensorflow running Python 3.5, activated it and ran pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow to install tensorflow._ Don't use pip in a Conda environment unless absolutely necessary, see for example https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment

Comment: Same problem here. I created a conda env but install packages with pip and VSCode can't find the packages...