# Unable to activate external modules in comand line or VS code "DLL load failed"

Tags: python, conda

I'm unable to import any external packages currently installed on any of my conda enviroments on either VS code or the command line.

For example after running the below command for my `scripts` env:

`C:\Users\UserName>C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\scripts\\python.exe -c "import pandas"`

The below traceback message is displayed:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\scripts\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

I can run the same command in the Anaconda Prompt terminal (or import pandas on a Jupyter Notebook) and no Traceback is displayed. Thank you in advance.

Note:: I've used this page as [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753825/modules-installed-in-conda-environment-not-being-found-by-vs-code?noredirect=1)

Comment: _For example after running the below command for my scripts env:_ Does it work if you activate the environment, and then run Python from there? How did you create the environment?

Comment: I've created the enviroment with conda, and it works once enviroment is activated with the anaconda prompt. When using vs code or running the above command on the cmd I can use standard library imports but not external packages. I get the dll load traceback error.