# vscode automatically "source activate" everytime launches new terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda

Recently when I'm using vscode, everytime I launches the built-in terminal, it automatically uses "source activate base" to launch a anaconda python virtual environment. You can see the screenshot

[image: here.]

I don't think I changed anything but it just came up randomly. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

To prevent automatic activation of a selected environment, add

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false
```

to your **settings.json** file (it can be placed anywhere as a sibling to the existing settings). However, debugging or running Python code without any activated environment won't work.

Comment: how do you change the environment ? i.e. instead of base can it automatically activate a different environment ?

Comment: nvm .. found it https://stackoverflow.com/a/50993392/805588