# How can I use Anaconda distribution Python path downloaded in the WSL(Windows Ubuntu 16) as the main python in VSCODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I use Python path downloaded in the Linux/WSL(Windows Ubuntu 16) as the main python in VSCODE?

Python Paths

Windows Python path: ***C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda3***

LINUX/Subsystem/WSL Python path: ***/root/anaconda3***

**Current setup**

OS **Windows 10**
Text Editor **VScode**
Python path (Editor settings) ***C:\Users\Sam\Anaconda3***
Subsytem/WSL **Ubuntu Terminal**

**Preferred Setup**

OS **Windows 10**
Editor: **VScode**
Python path (Editor Settings): ***/root/anaconda3***
Terminal: ***Wsl ubuntu terminal***

Basically I want to direct my **VSCode** to the **Linux python** path instead of the **windows python** path. To get from Linux **root** to windows **C:/** directory I go through **mnt/c/Users**

Comment: Please check the description of tags before blindly applying them! In particular, the "linux" tag was misapplied.

Comment: perhaps that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43352598/6195824 helps?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

[Install and set up the 'Remote - WSL' extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) which will let you run VS Code within WSL. Then you can install the Python extension in WSL. From there you should create an Anaconda environment with a specified Python version and then it will be [discoverable by the Python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) where you can click in the status bar to trigger the environment selection.