# Use environment variables in VS Code launch configurations

Tags: visual-studio-code

This question is related to [this question about conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351596/activating-anaconda-environment-in-vscode), and it is pretty straightforward:

How can I use an **external** environment variable inside `launch.json`?

For instance, selecting the python executable inside my home with `$HOME`, or the executable:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: From Home",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "$HOME/Documents/a.py", // nor does "${HOME}" work
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

or

```
    {
        "name": "Python: With Anaconda",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "python": "${HOME}/anaconda3/bin/python3",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

This would simplify sharing `launch.json` with coworkers.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables

Comment: @rioV8 that is working, `${env:USERNAME}`, thanks! If you turn it to an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Environment variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables)

The syntax is like `${env:USERNAME}`

Comment: how do you set them?

Comment: @JulesG.M. Depends on your OS/shell, search for `environment variables` and OS or shell like `bash` or `cmd` or `powershell` or `....`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attribute "env". For example:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,

            // ENVINRONMENT VARIABLES
            "env": {                 
                "VAR_A": "value_a",
                "VAR_B": "value_b"

            }
        }
    ]
}
```