# Python: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, path, anaconda

I tried to import `numpy` but I received a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` error. Someone told me it could be because I didn't have numpy installed, but I already did.

upon installing `numpy` I got `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.

`which python` returns `/Users/MacBook/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`. I am new at this, but I'm guessing the reason I got that error was because the files aren't in the same place? If so, how do I move it to the right place?

side note: I have a similar issue with `matplotlib` and this is running on VS code if that helps. Also I use `spyder` and I don't get the `numpy` nor the `matplotlib` error over there, but the error seems to be on VS code

Comment: You probably have different python versions on your computer, you're running one and the module is installed in the other

Comment: Have you activate conda? `conda activate base` More over in VS Code you can select the environment. Can you check that too?

Comment: @mozway I figure that could be a possibility, but 1. how do I check the version on my computer vs the one on VS code, and 2. how do I get them to be the same version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda installs its own conda environment to run python. Probably VS Code can't access. Try this command;

`python -mpip install numpy`

If your python file named numpy.py, you can get this error too.

If doesn't work maybe you can try to change the environment to Anaconda environment.
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351596/activating-anaconda-environment-in-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling `numpy` and re-installing. You also try re-install `anaconda`. I had this same issue and that fixed it.

Comment: I uninstalled already and had it reinstalled but it still return error