# Python VSC Visual Studio Code Can't find any of the modules: No module named 'sqlalchemy' No module named 'colorama'

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, module, anaconda3

UPDATE

I fully uninstalled anaconda: https://setapp.com/how-to/uninstall-anaconda-on-mac

I reinstalled it, updated it, and I can even see in the list: sqlalchemy

```
sqlalchemy                1.4.32           py39hca72f7f_0
```

But I keep on getting: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

So, it's like if Visual Studio Code doesn't have the correct path to the new version of Anaconda or Python.

I just installed:

```
pip3 install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

but nothing changed

ORIGINAL

My terminal was constantly redirected to a specific folder, which was very annoying, so I deleted it.

So, now I'm in the root.

But when I try to import a file in VSCode it can't find any of the modules:

So, following many suggestions, in Visual Studio Code I changed the cwd and tried many things:

```
Terminal › Integrated: Cwd => Empty, ${fileDirname}, public, ... none work
```

I tried to reinstall:

```
Conda install sqlalchemy

conda install psycopg2
```

It installed it, but if I run:

```
sqlalchemy --version
```

I get => -bash: sqlalchemy: command not found

These are the versions at root level:

```
pip --version => pip 21.2.4
python --version => Python 3.9.7
conda --version => conda 4.12.0
conda list anaconda$ => anaconda  2021.11  py39_0  
conda list python -f => python  3.9.7  h88f2d9e_1
conda list => I could publish this if you think it would help ( long list though )
conda info => same thing
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

[Activating Anaconda Environment in VsCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351596/activating-anaconda-environment-in-vscode)

Basically,

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search Select Interpreter
3. It was suggesting me a " Recommended version 3.9.10 64 bit". So, every time I would select that one.
4. The solution was to go to Terminal and check which version I had.

```
 > python3 --version
```

it gave me version `3.9.7`. So, I selected that one, which was called "Conda"