# Conda doesn't see a module in the same directory

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, modulenotfounderror, virtual-environment

When I try to run a script in conda environment it gives me a ModuleNotFound error

```
(ldm) C:\Users\Иван\Documents\git\stable-diffusion>python scripts/txt2img.py --prompt "a photograph of an astronaut in space" --plms 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ldm.util import instantiate_from_config 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldm'
```

Here are the **txt2img.py**'s lines causing the trouble

```
from ldm.util import instantiate_from_config
from ldm.models.diffusion.ddim import DDIMSampler
from ldm.models.diffusion.plms import PLMSSampler
```

But the main points are:

1. There is a folder called "ldm" containing everything needed
2. There are no complains from the compiler in the actual code editor

What I'm sure of:

- The **txt2img.py**'s directory is C:\Users\Иван\Documents\git\stable-diffusion\scripts\txt2img.py and the **ldm**'s directory is C:\Users\Иван\Documents\git\stable-diffusion\ldm
- Anaconda is added to my PATH environment variable
- I'm trying to make it work in VSCode terminal (I set it up to run conda) but it's absolutely the same in the separate Anaconda Prompt
- The problem does not occur with other projects

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got resolved with typing in the following:

```
pip install -e .
```

I think it just installs all the packages from the project folder

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution try the following:

```
cd C:\Users\Иван\Documents\git\stable-diffusion

C:\Users\Иван\Documents\git\stable-diffusion> python scripts\txt2img.py --prompt "a photograph of an astronaut in space" --plms
```

In VSCode, do the following:

1. Add 'C:\Users\Иван\Documents\git\stable-diffusion' to your workspace
2. Open VSCode Terminal (`ctrl` + `~`)
3. Follow the steps [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50993392/2825570)
4. Run your script

```
python scripts\txt2img.py --prompt "a photograph of an astronaut in space" --plms
```

**Update based on comment:**

You need to add an empty `__init__.py` inside all your folders. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/2825570)

Comment: I already selected my virtual environment, which is also called "ldm", as the workspace's interpreter. That's why there are no compains in the code editor. And actually it doesn't complain about any packages when I run the script, the only thing it doesn't see is the folder. And of course I've already cd'ed into the base folder

Comment: Updated my solution, kindly check

Comment: Tried it out and unfortunately it's all the same. My conda's python version is 3.8.5 so based on the info you provided, I don't need the __init__.py, as it's no longer requiered in 3.3+ versions of python

Comment: can you add these 2 lines at the top of txt2img.py script. `import os print(os.getcwd())` and show the output

Comment: Just solved this problem