# effective way to Activate Conda in VSCode on a Linux-Notebook

Tags: python, conda

....I was struggling a bit while I started to use VSCode, because there is a lot of flexibility in VSCode; it is one of the most flexible-projects on github: Well - but it also implies that there is tons of detailed settings which allows all kinds of alternative usages.

I am wondering how to go the head-to-toe process of how to use Conda environment in VSCode.

Well i have found some ideas how to do that focusing on Windows system, but wait: i want to do this on Linux:

See the win option: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/efficient-way-to-activate-conda-in-vscode-ef21c4c231f2

Here we add three things in the configurations:

```
“python.pythonPath”:“C:\\Users\\<your-usrname>\\Anaconda3\\envs\\<your-conda-env>\\python.exe”

“python.terminal.activateEnvironment”: true

“terminal.integrated.shell.windows”: “C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe”,
```

well - but what about doing this in Linux:

i guess that the short way of doing this would be like so:

first of all -
install conda; then
setup env in conda
install vscode; and finally
choose env in vscode

but how to do this concrete? Any ideas how to do this effectively?

for my solution i will try out the following:

[Activating Anaconda Environment in VsCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351596/activating-anaconda-environment-in-vscode)

Simply use

shift + cmd + P
Search Select Interpreter
pyhton : Select Interpreter
Simply use

[image]

Select it and it will show you the list of your virtual environment created via conda and other python versions
Activating conda virtual environment

[image]

select the environment and you are ready to go.
Quoting the 'Select and activate an environment' docs

Selecting an interpreter from the list adds an entry for python.pythonPath with the path to the interpreter inside your Workspace Settings.

Select it and it will show you the list of your virtual environment created via conda and other python versions
Activating conda virtual environment

cf: [Activating Anaconda Environment in VsCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351596/activating-anaconda-environment-in-vscode)

note: i will try out this solution.

i have found the basic manual here this:

see: **Visual Studio Code on Linux**
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

and this here: Microsoft Visual Studio Code and Anaconda
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/vscode/

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you expect to happen. It also helps if you describe what you tried already.

Comment: good day dear Ulrich - many thanks for the reply.  i need to do the setup and activate VSCode with Conda ( with the env etc ) .. in the steps.  I need to find a pathway to get this started - on a linux box