# VS Code: python.exe works in terminal only when opened from Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, visual-studio-code

When launching Visual Studio Code from the Anaconda Navigator page, the `python` command works correctly in the integrated terminal (Powershell or Bash).

However, when Visual Studio Code is launched normally (from start menu), `python.exe` is not found in the terminal (not in path).

Is there a way to always apply Anaconda's config to VS Code, to avoid having to launch it from the Anaconda Navigator page?

Answer (score 2):

When you installed Anaconda you probably had it leave the copy of Python in your base environment off of `PATH`. That means when you open your terminal it won't be found normally (this isn't specific to VS Code). One way to deal with this is to create conda environments for your project as those will get activated in the terminal when you use the `Python: Create Terminal` command. That will then make `python` available as a command from your terminal.

Comment: Yes it was recommended to leave Anaconda's `python.exe` off the `PATH`. I just would like to know what config is set by Anaconda when launching VS Code from Anaconda Navigator, and set it automatically when VS Code is launched from the start menu or command line. I don't want to set a specific env for each workspace.

Comment: Seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199846/how-can-i-launch-an-exe-within-a-conda-env

Comment: There is no config. The Anaconda Navigator is just manipulating `PATH` before launching VS Code.

Comment: And I would highly recommend creating an environment per workspace to keep your dependencies separate and independent per project.

Comment: You're right that it's better to create a separate env for projects/workspaces. But here I just would like to have access to `python`, `pip` etc. from code's integrated terminal, outside of a specific workspace and without setting it in Windows' global path. It works by launching code from Anaconda Navigator so i thought that it would be possible to set the correct path automatically while launching code.

Comment: There might be a settings like `terminal.integrated.shellArgs` that you could play with to get what you're after.